# Ubuntu & SVN: Dependency path clearly screwed up

Tags: svn

So when I try to use SVN from the command line on Ubuntu (just installed it), I get this error message:

> svn: /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information
>   available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libserf-1.so.1)
>
> svn: /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version
>   information available (required by
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libserf-1.so.1)

Clearly, something is screwed up because it's trying to get ssl and cyrpto libs from my plexmediaserver installation. Just not sure how exactly to fix this so it finds what it actually needs.

Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: more weirdness, some commands work and others don't.

svn checkout [URL] - worked just fine

svn info - worked just fine

svn status - get the error

Comment: What is the output of `ldd $(which svn)`?

Comment: How did you install subversion? `apt-get`? What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution, slightly less pleasant than otherwise, but it works.

Going into my Plex Media Center installation, I followed the path to those two dependency files and renamed them to have a .txt extension. This meant they were no longer being detected on the PATH, and it instead defaulted to the correct versions of these dependencies. Fortunately, this did NOT break Plex, as I guess the standard dependencies are more than good enough for it as well.